# overall Information of content

Tags: nodes

I have created content on 30/8/15 and the same created content is edited by other user on 1/9/15, when I go check in the dashboard or if i create view and see the edited only i could see, but in my case i want to see overall like when the content is created and by whom its created and also by whom edited?on what date for that particular content I want to see it in a view. how to achieve this please can any one suggest me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if you haven't enabled revisions for your content type, please enable like below:

admin/structure/types/manage/[your-content-type]

[image]

After that you need to create view to show revisions like below:

[image]

This will help you to achieve all information of event on node.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: if i follow this i could see all the created content node right? i want only for specific content type. i want to track only one content type not all, thanks in advance

Comment: You can enable revisions for your required content type. And In view pass filter criteria "content type" for which you want to track changes.

Comment: :do i need to select the filter condition as content type? well i want to track the user also ,that who all are editing the content.

Comment: I have added one more image please have look. You can try adding required fields and filters accordingly. Further you can explore relationships of author and user fields etc basic controls available in views. Thanks!

Comment: Have look at https://www.drupal.org/project/diff  module helps to track the difference between revisions as well.

Comment: Thank u so much, and also sorry that i keep on asking you, but i want to capture the user also that  who are editing are adding the content along with the date. please i am not getting it please share that along with this how to track the user....sorry again for asking

Comment: not a problem, I have updated image with help of that you can set view and track the user user who have made changes to your node :)

Comment: Thanks i am close to my requirement. i will try again with other methods and update you on monday.):):):):